# How can I move a Trello board into an organization when previously not in an organization?

Tags: trello

I have a board that was previously not in an organization.  I need to now move it into an organization.  I've noticed in the settings of the board that the "change organization" option is grayed out.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Further to what Bret said, if you are the administrator then you can change it by following this flow:

1. Go the respective board;
2. In the right hand menu go *Board* → *Menu* → *Settings* → **Change Organisation** (2nd option ).

Comment: To clarify, "the right hand menu" is the nav bar looking thing to the right side of the board; http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/31370/in-trello-how-do-i-display-the-right-side-menu-welcome-members-etc

Answer (score 2):

You'll be able to change the organization of the board only if you are an administrator of the board. If you're not an admin, you can ask any of the current board admins to change your board role to 'Admin'.

Answer (score 0):

Terms in Trello appear to have been changed now.

1. Go to the respective board
2. Go Menu --> More --> Settings --> Change Team... (1st option)