# In Trello, How do I display the right side menu ("Welcome, Members, etc)

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Board doesn't look the same](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30718/board-doesnt-look-the-same)

I've managed to "Lose" the right side menu in Trello.com.  How can I get it to display again.?  This is the right side menu area that shows members, recent board activity, etc . . .

Answer (score 2):

Hover near the right side of the window (just to the left of the window's frame) and you'll notice a "shadow" effect.  In Windows 7, the mouse cursor changes to a double-ended arrow when you're in the right area. Click in that area and the menu will reappear.